# Can I run a script on my LOCAL windows machine from PuTTY?

Tags: windows-7, windows, ssh, putty, twitter

I use a command line twitter client, [TTYtter](http://cdkaiser.sdf.org/ttytter/), thru PuTTY on a linux box.  Lots of tweets contain links, so there's a `/url` command to open urls, which searches for URLs a in a given tweet and runs a command on them locally to launch a browser with that url (e.g. `open %U` on mac or `firefox -new-tab %U` on Linux).

My question: **Is there a command I can run from within a PuTTY session to open a URL in my local (windows 7) machine?**  To put it another way: is there a way, from within an SSH session in PuTTY, to reach out of the SSH session to the local machine?

EDIT: Another approach: **Is there any combination of PuTTY and a windows ssh daemon or cygwin or something that I could use to ssh to my local box (loopback) and trigger a tab to open?**  I use tmux for multiplexing so my goal is to have all my stuff in one putty window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this probably doesn't work in a lot of cases, but here's what I came up with:

1. Run a service on the host machine that listens for incoming URLs.

   I used [NodeJS](http://nodejs.org/#download) here for no particular reason; I'm sure most popular scripting languages would work.

   ```
   var http = require('http'),
     querystring = require('querystring'),
     cp = require('child_process'),
     ip = '127.0.0.1',
     port = 9090,
     links_opened = 0;
     //urlopen curl --data "url=%U" 10.0.2.2:9090 %U  <- cmd for ttytter
   http.createServer(function (req, res) {
     if (req.method == 'POST') {
       req.on('data', function(chunk) {
     //get URL
         var _post = querystring.parse(chunk.toString()),
         //url has extra quotes for some reason:
           url_to_open = _post.url.match(/^'(.*)'$/)[1],
         //these three lines are just for nicely numbered console history (up to 999)
           link_ind = ++links_opened + ".",
           ln = link_ind + Array(5 - link_ind.length).join(' ');//pad it
           console.log( ln + url_to_open);
     //open tab
         cp.spawn('c:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe', ['-new-tab', url_to_open]);
       });
     }

     req.on('end', function() {
       //respond w/204 (success, no output)
       res.writeHead(204);
       res.end();
     });
   }).listen(port, ip);
   console.log('Server running at http://' + ip + ":" + port);
   ```
2. Send URLs from the host to the guest (I used cURL).

   In my `.ttytterrc`, I define the urlopen option thus: `urlopen curl --data "url=%U" 10.0.2.2:9090 %U` (%U is expanded to the URL: see [urlopen](http://cdkaiser.sdf.org/ttytter/copts.html)).

I call /url <tweet ID>, it sends a request to my host machine, and the node service opens a new tab in my current browser window.  I'm sure there are a host of potential security issues here, but given proper firewall settings, IP checks in the nodeJS script, etc., these are not showstoppers.  Anyway, it works for me!

Answer (score 3):

PuTTY doesn't support the launching of local applications unless of course you are connected via SSH to the local machine. One option is to install [Cygwin](http://cygwin.com) on your Windows box and install TTYtter on there. Essentially TTYtter is a collection of Perl scripts and should work fine on Cygwin assuming you have Perl installed as well.

Comment: Furthermore, if you use Cygwin's mintty terminal, you can just Ctrl+click on a link to open it in your default browser.